# How to create a quiz like this?

Tags: javascript, html

http://bitecharge.com/play/realbirth#q3.6e6e

in the above quiz when you answer a question it refreshes on the same page, the whole page does not gets refreshed.
How can i create a similar quiz?

Comment: [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or iframes/frames

Answer (score 2):

well you can do this many ways:

1 - On the clients browser you can keep track of all responses in an array using javascript, once the user is done you can post that array to the server either with regular http POST request, or with an Ajax request.

2 - if you want the server to know users response as soon as a user clicks you can post the response using Ajax on every click.